# In Android, why is it bad to allocate an object in the onDraw()?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I know we shouldn't do it, and I know the method might get called hundreds of times, but is there any other reason?
More specifically, is there any OpenGL related reason?

Comment: [Optimizing the View: Do Less, Less Frequently](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/optimizing-view.html#less)

Answer (score 0):

No. The reason is the one you said. OpenGL does not care what objects you instantiate and when. It's just inefficient.